# Web-sockets doesnt work after uploading files on hosting

Tags: javascript, php, ws

Why isn't the web socket working? I use Workerman. I did a chat on a local server, everything worked fine there, however, when uploading to a remote server, an error began to appear in [info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlZnz.png)the console: WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. I thought it was because I was using ws and on the server I had https. I added the certificates (ssl-certificate - .pem; private-key - .key) however it also kept throwing this error. What happened, maybe it's in the server? I'm using PHP CLI 5.4.[code js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJT9B.png)[php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5AYU.png)[ssl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tntvk.png)

UPD. I asked my hosting to reinstall ssl, after connecting it I get this error: SSL handshake error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success

UPD2. it started working, but the connection is immediately disconnected[scretnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NhWM.png)

Comment: PHP 5.4 is an unsupported version as you can see [here](https://www.php.net/eol.php) and it's end of life was 7 years and half ago. Consider moving to 8.1 that is the latest version

Comment: I updated PHP, I continue get this problem

Comment: the error you are getting is not related to PHP, the problem is that the SSL certificate you use is not considered valid on the server side. It can be either a self signed certificate or the issuer authority can be considered invalid or you are using a wildcard certificate or many other issues. You are not providing any debugging detail so it's just guessing

Comment: it's strange, 
the certificate was issued by the same company from which I rent hosting, what debugging details can i provide you?

Comment: then probably it is a self signed certificate. and this means it is considered invalid. you should use let's encrypt for a free but valid certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably requires a valid ssl certificate and not a self-signed one.
You can try letsencrypt and use the nginx proxy.

Comment: It isn't self-signed certificate.

Comment: ssl v3? v2 is not supported.

Comment: I saw that the service is using IP instead of domain, have you tried typing domain instead of 31.31.196.193? Like websocket://tuodomain.something:2346/.

Comment: yes, problem still exist

Comment: Try this for test:
[link](https://github.com/walkor/workerman-chat/issues/12)

Comment: I change my certificate (change type certificate from .pem to .crt) and i got this problem: SSL handshake error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Unable to set private key file `/var/www/u1890584/data/w
ww/drimgostudio.online/certificate.crt'

Comment: Because certificate.crt isn't private Key.